# MongoDb authentication mechanism in java

Tags: java, mongodb, authentication

I just completed a mongodb java project without authentication. Now I want to add authentication to it. So I went to mongodb website trying to figure out how and which way is the best. I was presented with a lot of [authentication mechanisms](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#mongo-shell-authentication-mechanisms). The descriptions are not just enough to make me understand which method is the best. Which means I would have to read every mechanism in detailed which will be time consuming for now. I tried the ScramSha1 as in my code below.

Am very concerned because I really want my system to be well secured.

```
      try{ // Manage the mongo db connection...
            List<ServerAddress> seeds = new ArrayList<>();
            seeds.add( new ServerAddress( host,intPort ));
            List<MongoCredential> credentials = new ArrayList<>();
            credentials.add(MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(userName,databaseName,password.toCharArray()));
            mongo = new MongoClient( seeds, credentials );
            db = mongo.getDB(databaseName);

        }catch(MongoException ex){

        }
```

**FROM EXPERIENCE, I hope Gurus here can tell me the best among the mechanisms and why. Thanks a lot in Advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any production ready application, I would recommend using certificate based authentication (x.509). This mechanism is more secure when compared to user name and password based mechanisms such as MONGODB-CR and SCRAM-SHA-1.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-x.509/#security-auth-x509

Nowadays, due to the high emphasis on IT security, the most recommended approach in the industry is to use the certificate based authentication (x.509).

1) If your application is for public users, I strongly recommend using the certificate based authentication
2) If it is an intranet based application used by internal organizational users, you can still go with certificate based authentication. In case, if it is not feasible (due to some reason), you can go ahead with SCRAM-SHA-1 (available from MongoDB version 3.0).